# Open URL in Photoshop CC?

Tags: javascript, url, photoshop

I'd like to open an url (google.de) in Photoshop when I press a button.

I've tried it with :

```
var url = "http://www.google.de";
system.callSystem("explorer " + url);
```

and:

```
this.that.window.open("http://www.google.de", "Zweitfenster", "width=300,height=400,left=100,top=200");
```

But without luck.

Also I couldn't record it when I tried to open the adobe link in photoshop. (it's not recorded).

Comment: anyone has somethign for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way:

```
var site="www.google.de"; //your side

      if (  $.os.indexOf("Windows") != -1 ) 

      {//SYSTEM IS ONE OF THE WINDOWS
                          app.system("cmd.exe /c\"start http://"+site+"\"" );
                }
                          else{//MUST BE MAC
                          system.callSystem("open http://"+site);
          }
```

app.system = instead of system.callSystem !!
Bind on a button and it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

another way to open url, by execute batch file(for Windows)

```
var bat = new File("/test.bat");
bat.execute();
```

test.bat

---

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" "http://google.com"
cls
exit
```

---